# Best way to restore .git folder

Tags: git, restore, timemachine

Due to some error in code, we lost a complete GIT-controlled directory. Restoring the files was not a problem; TimeMachine took care of that. However, TimeMachine apparently did not back up the .git folder.

Is there a better way to restore/recreate the .git folder than to fetch the directory from the master server or another machine?

Thanks in advance for any useful hint.

Comment: If you have pushed all changes why hesitate to use your master to fetch your .git folder?

Comment: "TimeMachine apparently did not back up the .git folder." That's a scary thought. Can someone confirm this? How about other dot-directories?

Comment: A quick google search shows that Time Machine must be manually configured to avoid backing up .git directories, so unless you have purposely set it up that way, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Update: the .git directory did get restored. Not noticing it is my fault. However, somehow the .gitconfig file got messed up and I get a "malformed" error message… further investigations. So, thanks for the help in any case.

Answer (score 19):

You can check out a bare .git repo and then inflate it into a full repo by adding your source code. This will still download the entire .git folder but not your working copy code files.

1. Create a new folder and navigate to it.
2. Clone a bare repo:

   `git clone --bare https://path/to/project .git`
3. Copy your locally recovered files around the .git folder (in the same relative location as they were earlier).
4. Mark the new repo as non-bare:

   `git config --local --bool core.bare false`
5. Finally reset the index:

   `git reset HEAD -- .`

Comment: Isn't it more easy to clone normally to a new spare directory and move the ".git" folder from the spare directory to the project folder (where it was originally)?

Comment: @Readren the question asked for restoring the .git directory without fetching everything from the server.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 options:

```
1. restore it form backup (which i assume you don't have) 
2. clone the repository again and compare the content to add the modified content.
```

Since .git is simply folder with content.

If you did not backup it with Time Machine so you will have to clone it again.