# git find commit from "working tree"

Tags: git, restore

Suppose a person cloned a git repository and deleted the .git folder. Is there a way to recover which commit they were on? This isn't a duplicate of [Best way to restore .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24775326/1248889) or [Can deleted .git be restored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6246907/1248889), because *years* have past since this event. I'm now trying get it back under git to update it to a new version. However, changes may have been introduced in those years, that I need to merge/rebase onto the new version.

My current idea is to:

1. Clone the current repository from github into another folder using `git clone --bare`
2. Mark the repo as non-bare using `git config --local --bool core.bare false`
3. Copy the files from the mystery version into this folder
4. Save a diff of the working tree with the current commit hash somewhere
5. Update HEAD to HEAD^ (Not really sure how to do this step without modifying the working tree. Potentially switching back to bare, checkout HEAD^ switch back to non-bare? I've also read about git symbolic-ref plumbing but don't know how to use it)
6. Repeat steps 4-5 until at root
7. Choose the diff with the smallest size. That should be a good approximation to the commit that this code diverged from. Search around that commit for the exact divergence point.

Is there a better way? There's a semver, but it wasn't updated very much so it only cuts down the range to around a year or two. I don't believe the repository was changed much, so I'd guess there are exact matching files. Maybe I could use that information to narrow down the possible commits? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do:

1. commit the actual sources into some branch (e.g. `_tmp_`), so that index is clean
2. iterate over all possible commits (e.g. `git rev-list master`) and check the diff

   `git rev-list master | while read rev; do 
     git diff "$rev" "_tmp" && echo "it is $rev!"
   done`

   When `_tmp_` contains files which are untracked in the repository, the `git diff` will never succeeded and you have to analyze the diffs (e.g. this with lowest `wc -l` wins).

Comment: Thanks, this set me in the right direction. `git diff` will print/invoke the viewer. Additionally it looks like all whitespace was changed. So I replaced the command with ``echo "$rev" `git diff -w --shortstat "$rev" "_tmp_" >> ../diffs.txt`` then scanned though and found the one with the least insertions/deletions.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same need, but the working tree I had to inspect also contained modifications, hence I built a script on top of ensc's answer that automates the process of finding the commit with the least differences.

It is available at https://github.com/deribaucourt/git-find-worktree.