How to find the most likely revision of a project which was used to start a fork?
I have a modified Klipper installed on my 3D printer, but they didn't cleanly fork the original repo so I don't know on which revision they based their changes.
I would like to backport features from mainline to my printer modified version (replacing it as a whole is not an option) and I would like to know where to start.
How can I find the most likely mainline commit to start with? even dates are not useful for the purpose, I only know it's before a certain date (2024-05-10).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49059767/git-find-commit-from-working-tree/ , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473306/how-to-find-the-certain-commit-of-an-outdated-file/73474235#73474235

May be you can just merge mainline?

@phd I'm afraid there will be too much work, and my skills are limited. I was more planning to hand pick commits which both bring visible and usable improvements and which require little to no modifications to the code for merging. I'll check your two links

If I find which commit the fork is based on, I could detect the changes made and apply only them to mainline
